# How can I tell data arrives on a HTTP keep-alive connection?

Tags: sockets, http, keep-alive, libuv

I am implementing a simple web server using libuv. Currently I am stuck with the keep-alive connection.

Based on my understanding of keep-alive, I just do not call `uv_close()` on the established connection(a TCP socket) after a request is processed, and reuse it latter.

I am wondering how can I tell a new request arrives on that connection?
That is, when should I call `uv_read_start()` on that alive connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use keep-alive, the connection will not be closed after the first request. When the client wants to send a new request, it will just reuse the same connection, so your read callback will be called again. You shouldn't even need to call uv_read_start() again.

Answer (score 1):

Immediately you have finished writing the prior response.